# Access Magento API through localhost to avoid network latency

Tags: api, ce-1.8.1.0, base-url, localhost

I have a Magento site and an external app that communicates with it via the Magento API. For the moment, the second app is hosted in the same server as the Magento installation. The Magento API can be very slow, and I think the fact that an API call has to be resolved in a DNS server (the request must go out of the network and then come back to the same server) has something to do with it.

**Is there a way that I can use a different url** (`http://localhost`) **to tell the second app that it is a local request** and maybe reduce response time? I cannot change `base_url` or the site would stop working.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly improbable that the slow response is being caused by a slow DNS resolution.

You can try to use [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) to better diagnose.

You can also try to modify your hosts file and add your domain to make it resolve to 127.0.0.1 instead of the domains IP (not sure about your webserver configuration, it might require some additional work).